# Wget simplify asset filenames from downloading

Tags: web, command-line, download, wget, mirroring

I am downloading a website with wget with the following command line:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p --no-directories  --content-disposition https://example.com/hello.index
```

When I've downloaded the assets, this is how the file directory looks like:

```
index.html.orig
index.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.engadget.com%2Fimg%2Fproducts%2F503%2Fasu0%2Fasu0.jpg
index.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.engadget.com%2Fimg%2Fproducts%2F536%2Fbi6i%2Fbi6i.jpg
index.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.engadget.com%2Fimg%2Fproducts%2F547%2Fbqt8%2Fbqt8.jpg
...
```

Is there a way that I can instruct wget to download the website such that the names of the files will be:

```
index.html.orig
asu0.jpg
bi6i.jpg
bqt8.jpg
...
```

and the index.html file be named appropriately?

Comment: Does adding `--trust-server-names` do anything?

Comment: @Trey Nope, it does not do anything